# How to get available free disk space in bytes?

Tags: ubuntu, disk-usage

I'm trying to get total free disk space to make its filling prognosis.

The ways I've already used

```
df -h

Filesystem      Avail
/dev/md1p1      182G
none            488K
tmpfs           32G
tmpfs           13G
tmpfs           5.0M
tmpfs           6.3G



df -Bk

Filesystem      1K-blocks  Available
/dev/md1p1     431550588K 189781520K
none                 492K       488K
tmpfs           32869168K  32869168K
tmpfs           13147668K  13147504K
tmpfs               5120K      5120K
tmpfs            6573832K   6573832K
```

What does prefix 'K' mean? Kilobytes?

What does 1K-blocks column mean?

How can I print all data measured in bytes?

Comment: If you read `man df` (the reference manual pages) it'll tell you exactly what the `K` means, and whether it's 1000 bytes or 1024

Comment: Disk devices work in blocks (whose size is determined by the type of file system). Blocks are always a multiple of 512 bytes, but normally 4096 bytes -- you can determine this by using `stat -f` on any file in the file system. Your resultant bytes will always be exactly divisible by the block size anyway, so not clear why a number like 98112299008 would be any more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

With the GNU implementation of `df`, as found on Ubuntu, you can use:

```
df --block-size=1
```

Or:

```
df -B 1
```

That explicitly sets the blocks to be 1 byte and displays the result

That takes precedence over the `$DF_BLOCK_SIZE` variable, itself taking precedence over `$BLOCK_SIZE` itself taking precedence over `$BLOCKSIZE` which are ways to specify the block size globally (and except for `$DF_BLOCK_SIZE` affect other commands such as GNU `ls -s` or GNU `du`).

The default block size for utilities in GNU coreutils when the `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable is not set is the [Kibibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Units_based_on_powers_of_2) aka KiB, aka K¹ which is 1024 or 2<sup>10</sup> bytes. So `df` by default is the same as `df -BK` or `df -B1024`.

See:

```
info df 'Block size'
```

for details.

So to get just two columns: filesystem source and available space (to non-root users) in bytes:

```
df --block-size=1 --output=source,avail
```

---

<sup>¹ but not KB/kB which is ambiguous and most of the times means 1000 bytes (kilobyte).</sup>